# How to create a typescript object from a stream

Tags: typescript, interface

I have a interface like this:

```
interface IMyInterface {
    prop1: number;
    prop2: number;
}
```

What is the best way to create an object based on this interface with values read from a stream?

This is what I try to do, but it does not work because o misses the properties in the first line:

```
let o: IMyInterface = {};
o.prop1 = stream.readUint32();
o.prop2 = stream.readUint32();
```

I could fix this when I make the properties optional, but this is not what I want.

This works but I am not sure if it is guaranteed that the values are read in the given order:

```
let o: IMyInterface = {
   prop1: stream.readUint32(),
   prop2: stream.readUint32()
};
```

I could solve it by using a class instead of the interface, but is there no receipt for this?

Greetings

Jochen

Comment: HashMap data structure has unordered keys. If you want to make sure that readUnit will be called in some order, please youse promises

Comment: do you mean that o is missing the properties from the interface? if so did you try let o: IMyInterface = {} as IMyInterface;